# data distribution based on primary key

Tags: database, key

Currently in one of my projects, we're supporting 32k entities, however it's reaching its limits for performance, and hence we're thinking of distributing it to different databases based on their integer primary keys. E.g. the first 35k will go to one db, the next 35k to the next db and so on (based on (primary key % #db) logic).

However, this will present a problem when we're inserting an entity into db. Since we don't know its primary key value beforehand, how do we figure out which db to insert it into?

One possibility is maintaining a global id table in only one db. So we insert into it first, get the primary key value and then use it to choose a db for further detailed insertion. But this solution is not uniform and hence difficult to maintain and extend. So any other thoughts on how to go about it?

Comment: 32K entries and performance problems :O - what database are you using ? Can you be sure it's not your design vs. the db that's the issue here ??

Comment: Actually the DB is not the bottleneck right now, but the middle layer. We need to process entries within 2 hrs, and processing an entry takes a few seconds on an average. So we need to scale out the middle tier. But once we scale that out, the DB may not be able to keep up with increased volume, hence sort of thinking ahead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this nice article that talks about how Flickr solved this problem:
http://code.flickr.com/blog/2010/02/08/ticket-servers-distributed-unique-primary-keys-on-the-cheap/